# Как в Windows Forms сделать надчеркивание?(логическое отрицание)

Tags: c#, winforms

Именно на формах, а не на wpf. 
Допустим, по нажатию кнопки выделенный текст надчеркивается, например: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы хотите применить к всему слову - просто поменяйте параметр надчёркивание в шрифте выделеного фрагмента. Если вас интерисуют детали - уточните какой именно компонент winforms вы используете. У richedit такая возможность менять шрифт заложена.

Comment: Там только зачеркнутый и подчеркнутый имеются

Comment: Покопайтесь в таблице юникода, там должен быть такой символ

Answer (score 3):

В WinForms с красивостями плохо. Надчеркивание стандартными средствами не возможно в принципе, т.к. за стиль шрифта в System.Drawing (GDI+) отвечает перечисление [FontStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.fontstyle(v=vs.110).aspx), которое ни чего не знает о надчеркивании. `RichTextBox` тут тоже не помощник, потому что его контент рисует все тот же System.Drawing (GDI+). В этом легко убедиться на примере стандартного WordPad, в котором раскрыты все или почти все возможности `RichTextBox` в плане форматирования текста, не хватает только некоторых возможностей rtf-разметки, которые впрочем не особенно и нужны в виду наличия более удобных и современных форматов.

**Альтернативные варианты:**

Для одной буквы можно воспользоваться [комбинированными символами unicode](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks/), а именно символом надчеркивания: код `0x0305`, например так: `"a\x0305"` - a̅; или так:`"Y\x0305"` - Y̅. Для длинного текста такой вариант не подходит, т.к. потребуется вставлять этот символ после каждой буквы текста. Плюс ко всему, такие составные символы не всегда корректно отображаются, надстрочные и подстрочные знаки могут "съезжать" в сторону, например так: ы̅

Можно разместить на форме хостинг для WPF контролов [ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) и воспользоваться всей оформительской мощью WPF.

На самый крайний случай всегда остается возможность просто нарисовать и текст и линии надчеркивания средствами System.Drawing (GDI+) на обычном `Bitmap` или прямо на контроле, но как вы понимаете, ни каком выделении текста мышкой и редактировании не может быть и речи, если конечно вы не страдаете от острого приступа мазохизма и/или трудоголизма =) ну или интерес исключительно академического характера.

Comment: в Unicode есть символы уже содержащие диакритические знаки: [Расширенная латиница — A (0100—017F), Расширенная латиница — B (0180—024F)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B,_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) но от съезжания это не спасёт, канешн

Comment: @Alias монолитные версии символов с диакритическими знаками я не стал упоминать, там есть очень ограниченный список символов. Для формул пожалуй лучше использовать именно их, но в случае "надчеркивания" произвольного текста это задачу не решает.